# How to assign permission set to multiple users based on profile?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, profile, user

I am trying to assign permission set to all users of specific profile. While doing this i'm getting errors.Please help me to solve this.

Error:
Line: 18, Column: 1
System.DmlException: Upsert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: DUPLICATE_VALUE, Duplicate PermissionSetAssignment. Assignee: 0052v00000eSqTK; Permission Set: 0PS2v000004upmS: [AssigneeId, PermissionSetId]

```
public class AssignPermissionSetToProfile {
@AuraEnabled
    public static void assignpermi(string profiles,string PermissionSett)
    {
        List<user> pro1=[select id,Profile.Name from user where Profile.Name=:profiles];
        
        PermissionSetAssignment permi2=[SELECT Id, PermissionSetId, PermissionSet.Name,PermissionSet.Profile.Name, 
                                        AssigneeId, Assignee.Name FROM PermissionSetAssignment where PermissionSet.Name=:PermissionSett limit 1];
        
        List<PermissionSetAssignment> permiList=new  List<PermissionSetAssignment>();
        
        for(user one:[SELECT Id,UserRole.Name,Profile.Name,IsActive FROM User WHERE Profile.Name =: profiles AND IsActive = true])
        {
            PermissionSetAssignment psa = new PermissionSetAssignment(PermissionSetId = permi2.PermissionSetId, AssigneeId = one.Id);
              permiList.add(psa);
              
        }
        upsert permiList;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd guess that the permission set has already been assigned to a given user...?

Comment: Isn't this what permission set groups are for?

Answer (score 1):

Got solution for it

```
public class AssignPermissionSetToProfile {
@AuraEnabled
    public static void assignpermi(string profiles,string Sett)
    {
        PermissionSet permii=[select id from PermissionSet where Name=:Sett];
        List<PermissionSetAssignment> permiList=new  List<PermissionSetAssignment>();
        List<PermissionSetAssignment> userinfo=[SELECT AssigneeId FROM PermissionSetAssignment WHERE PermissionSet.Name =:Sett];
        set<Id> userId=new set<Id>();
        for(PermissionSetAssignment dd:userinfo)
        {
            userId.add(dd.AssigneeId);
        }
        for(user one:[SELECT Id,UserRole.Name,Profile.Name,IsActive FROM User WHERE Profile.Name =: profiles ])
        {
            if(userId.contains(one.Id))
            {
                system.debug('Already added user');
            }
            else
            {
            PermissionSetAssignment psa = new PermissionSetAssignment(PermissionSetId = permii.id, AssigneeId = one.Id);
            permiList.add(psa);
            }
        }
        upsert permiList;
    }
}
```